# List.iter & List.fold_right used together

Tags: ocaml

I am trying to use the fold_right and List.iter functions in the List module.  Is there anyway to use them in conjunction with one another?

```
let step nfa start transition = 
  let transition_list = get_transition nfa in
  List.iter ( fun state ->
    List.fold_right (fun ct nl ->
       if ((get_pre_trans transition)= state && (get_trans ct) = transition) then
         (get_post_transition transition)::nl
       else
         nl
    ) transition_list []
  ) start
;;
```

** The get_xxx functions get values from a tuple where there is a pre-transition, transition value, and post-transition.

Return error:
Error: This expression has type 'a list but an expression was expected of type unit.

Not sure what to do.

Comment: A lot of your code is missing and we can't help you without it. Where did you declare `new_list` or `get_trans`? Maybe you should check the type for those values.

Answer (score 3):

The body of the function that you pass to `iter` contains only one expression, a call to `fold_right`, that evaluates to a value of type `list`, but `iter` signature requires you to pass a function, that returns a value of type `unit`. That is basically what compiler tries to say to you. If you're not interested in the value to which `fold_right` is evaluated, then you can ignore it using `ignore` function, that takes a value of any type and returns a value of type `unit`. On the other hand, if you don't want to discard it, then you shouldn't use `iter`, and use `fold_right` or, better, `fold_left`.

And, finally, answering your question, yes, there're ways to combine them together, but usually, if you're applying a fold inside iter, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: So if I want to get the list back should I have the iter inside the fold?

Comment: in that case you need fold inside fold

Comment: Can you give an example of when to use List.iter vs. List.fold?  I thought I could use List.iter on the list of start states since I was not modifying any of those values.  I just wanted to use those values in the inner function.